# Laravel - Api request

Tags: api, curl, laravel-4

I have a website build with Laravel 4.2 and a controller that are accessible only to logged user:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pannello-utente', 'before' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('elenco-animali/{nome?}', ['uses' => 'PazientiController@index']);
    Route::get('download/{cartella}/{file}', ['uses' => 'PazientiController@download']);
});
```

the auth method request user to insert email and password.

In the `PazientiController` I have the `__construct` method that perform some queries that retrieve a code and use it in the other method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->current_user = Auth::user();

    //Recupero il codice cliente salvato nel profilo utente
    $this->codice = User::find($this->current_user->id)->first()->profile->codice_cliente;
}
```

This code is saved only in the database and, at the moment, no other application have it so I need to execute that query every time.

I need that, now via curl then via smartphone app, the user can access to the method, so I need users to log in before:

```
curl --user chri788@gmail.com:adminadmin localhost:8888/*****/public/pannello-utente/elenco-animali
```

But I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8888/*****/public/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8888/*****/public/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8888/******/public/login">http://localhost:8888/****/public/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I access to that controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--user` flag for curl triggers HTTP Basic Authentication. Laravel supports this, but not with the `auth` filter - it needs the `auth.basic` filter.

You can write a custom filter that checks both `auth` and `auth.basic`, or you can provide a separate set of routes (maybe prefixed with `api`) that uses the alternate filter.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#http-basic-authentication

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi Yes, something along those lines should do it. You could also build a proper API key system so you're not passing username/password around (especially if your passwords change)